# Stuck at writing a .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need some help writing a .htaccess file for the following scenario:

The user enters this address: `http://subdomain.domain.com/name` and should be redirected to `http://subdomain.domain.com/#/name`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch ^/name$ /#/name
```

or if you mean that "name" can be anything:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.+)$ /#/$1
```

Comment: Yes, the name can be anything actually, it's falling into a redirect loop right now, as it's redirecting from the url including the hash, I'll just have to avoid the redirect when the hash is already there. Thank you!